# Redirect URLs in Microsoft application registration

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In my Microsoft application registration, under "redirect URLs", I've checked `Allow Implicit flow` and provided the URL, `http://localhost:8080/event`.

But I actually have an dynamic event id which makes the URL `localhost:8080/event/{eventid}`.

So now I'm getting an error:

> The reply address `http://localhost:8080/student/event/59b67936d53f013a79000009` does not match the reply addresses configured for the application

How can I give a URL that will allow any value after the `event` in the URL?

Comment: i was looking for a wild card url that will match all the urls after "localhost:8080/event".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put more care into formatting your question. Please also read the help sections on asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a dynamic URI for OAUTH redirects. Note that this isn't specific to Microsoft's v2 Endpoint, this is the case for every OAUTH provider I've used.

I assume you're looking to redirect the user to a specific event page after they've completed the login?

The proper way to handle that is to use the [state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit#get-access-tokens) parameter. This is a string value and will be returned with the response. For example, you could encode your `eventid` an include that value in the `state`. When you get the token response back, you're app decodes the `state` value and redirects the user.